# Configure path-style in Java SDK Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm using [AWS Java SDK](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html) provided by Amazon to interact with the S3 service.

It seems that by default, the SDK uses virtual-host-style for buckets (i.e. buckets are reffered by *bucket-name*.s3.amazonaws.com. Example:

```
PUT / HTTP/1.1
Host: a-given-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: Tue, 26 Jun 2012 10:39:40 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
```

However, I need to use path-style in my application, as follows:

```
PUT /a-given-bucket/ HTTP/1.1
Host: s3.amazonaws.com
Date: Thu, 21 Jun 2012 16:27:32 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
```

Is it possible to use path-style with the Java SDK, please? In positive case, how can I do it? I have look at ClientConfiguration and AmazonS3Client classes but I don't see any method to do it...

My SDK version, in the case it matters, is: 2.0.0v201206151133.

Thanks!

---

Fermín

PD. Some headers have been omitted in the samples for the sake of simplicity.

**EDIT:**
Such a feature (to configure the URL path style used by the AmazonS3Client) is quite useful in case you have buckets with a dot (".") in them. HTTPS requests with Virtual-host-style do not work, see [this](http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/08/amazon-s3-gotcha-using-virtual-host.html) and [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html).

Comment: Also publised in AWS developers forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=98203

Answer (score 29):

The method *withPathStyleAccess* has been deprecated. Please use the following instead:

```
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3Client.builder()
            .withCredentials((new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)))
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("host", "region"))
            .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
            .build();
```

---

Deprecated method:

This is now possible, I'm not sure when it was introduced, but it's available in at least the 1.7.8 version of the Java AWS SDK.

Just call [setClientOptions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#setS3ClientOptions%28com.amazonaws.services.s3.S3ClientOptions%29) on your AmazonS3 instance:

```
AmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
client.setS3ClientOptions(new S3ClientOptions().withPathStyleAccess(true));
```

Answer (score 19):

For SDK v2 you can you enable path style by doing this:

```
public S3Client build() {
    S3Configuration config = S3Configuration.builder()
        .pathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
        .build();

    return S3Client.builder()
        .serviceConfiguration(config)
        // other set up
        .build();
}
```

[Amazon was planning to deprecate path style access from Sept 2020](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story). But [this deprecation has been postponed](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/update-to-amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan/).

Comment: This is good. Worked for SDK v2. For SDK v1 refer next answer.

Answer (score -1):

*This answer is out of date, left here for posterity. See the answer above.*

There's no way to force V1 (path-style) bucket addressing using the Java SDK.  The only exception is when your bucket name isn't DNS addressable, in which case the SDK will automatically use V1 addressing.  This happens, e.g., when your bucket name contains a period  (which is discouraged for this reason).

If you want this functionality, you'll have to modify the `AmazonS3Client` class to allow it.

https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-java/

However, I'm not sure I believe your claim that you "need" to use V1 bucket addressing.  The SDK already handles all cases where V1 addressing is necessary -- or if you have found a case where it doesn't, please let us know in the forums.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=70

Comment: Dear @Zach you will probably reject it but people often implement software that needs to be able to use AWS S3 as long as other compatible solutions and AWS SDK could be really good integration point. For example IBM SpectrumScale has S3 emulation support. You can say 'why do we need to support third-party solutions'. Think differently: why people should move to AWS S3? Only if they can put SDK that allows transition they can do it. And this requires full support of existing storage which works in emulation mode with some compatibility issues.

Comment: It is also not true, path-style access can be enforced as per @oggmonster answer