# Generate S3 URL in "path-style" format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

https://wincent.com/wiki/HTTPS_access_to_Amazon_S3_buckets
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html

Is there any way to use the Java SDK to generate a presigned S3 temporary URL in the path-style instead of the virtual-host-style?

Edit: To clarify:

path-style means `https://s3.amazonaws.com/my.bucket/my_item?...`

virtual-host style means `https://my.bucket.s3.amazon.aws.com/my_item?...`

Comment: Not sure you can do this, but I'm interested in why you prefer path-style.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm whether it's (not) possible. If not, then changing the bucket name would be the only way.

Comment: Could you please Edit your question to show what you mean by "path-style" and "virtual-host-style", for the benefit of future readers?

Comment: @jarmod you need path-style if your bucket name has dots in it, so that SSL will work.  The reference to "changing the bucket name" seems to imply that this might be the unstated problem that is being encountered and that first link suggests the same thing. I suspect that's it, because I can't really think of any other reason to want this behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution.

You create your `AmazonS3Client` by calling `withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)` on the `AmazonS3ClientBuilder`. For example in the following Scala code:

```
val amazonS3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
  .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
  .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
  .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
  .build()
```

And then you generate the URL the usual way.

```
val generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectName)
...
amazonS3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest).toString
```

The resulting URL will be path-style.

I wouldn't have bothered asking this question if I had seen [Configure path-style in Java SDK Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228792/configure-path-style-in-java-sdk-amazon-s3/24012996) ...