# How to change the format of S3Client.getURL

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-java-sdk

I'm using the AWS Java SDK within my Spring Boot app.
Currently, when i want to return the URL of the s3 object i use:

```
s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(S3_BUCKET_NAME, key,fileToUpload));
URL signedUrl = s3Client.getUrl(S3_BUCKET_NAME, key);
```

And the signedUrl looks like this :

```
https://<my_bucket_name>.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<my_key>
```

The problem is that this URL is invalid (it returns HTTPS error during connection). Right now, i cant configure my custom domain and resolve the problem via CloudFront configuration.

So my idea is to force the different format on the SDK. Something like this:

```
https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<my_bucket_name>/<my_key>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

PS:
I know that, i can do a simple replace on the URL but it is not an elegant solution.

Comment: What's the HTTPS error you received? Why do you think a different URL format will mitigate the HTTPS issue?

Comment: It yells, "Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN". my_bucket_name.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com uses an invalid security certificate. 

With ttps://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com i can mitigate the issue.

Comment: Are you  trying to access this URL in firefox? have you tried the URL in Chrome? Seems like there's a bug with firefox https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1049026

Comment: Chrome reports the same https error. What is strange that [coursera_assets_example](https://coursera_assets.s3.amazonaws.com/about/overview/about_discover_a_course_youre_interested_in.jpg) works fine in both browser. It looks like my bucket configuration is causing the issue.

Comment: @Anuruddha - Check my answer, it was my silly mistake. Therefore thanks for the conversation, it helped me to work it out.

Comment: You could try replacing the _ with - in the bucket name. Also you could check with the complete example provided in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html on S3 url signing and see if you are missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was with bucket name. The dot character in bucket name was causing all the trouble.

foo-bar-com as bucket name works as expected. 
foo.bar.cam.s3. bucket name is causing the https exception.

Comment: An S3 URL in the form `https://bucket.s3.region.amazonaws.com/key` is called *virtual-style access*, while `https://s3.region.amazonaws.com/bucket/key` is called *path-style access*.  The latter supports dots in the bucket name, while the former doesn't, due to the way wildcard SSL cert validation works.  I am not a Java developer, but see [`isPathStyleAccess`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/S3ClientOptions.html#builder--) for what I believe may have been your alternate solution.

Comment: It also appears that the preferred approach with the Java SDK has undergone several iterations over the years, c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24012996/1695906.

Comment: Note also that string replacing to reformat the URL from one style to the other is only usable with Signature V2, because the signature algorithm there uses the actual bucket name in its input; by contrast, Signature V4 uses the entire hostname in the URL as input to the signing algorithm, so string replacement in the URL -- which would necessarily change the hostname -- will also invalidate the signature... so, probably good that you didn't go this route.  One notable visual difference between the two is that Sig V2 URLs include `AWSAccessKeyId` while Sig V4 URLs include `X-Amz-Credential`.